# Load balancing in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

I want to conduct a HTTP load test.

I've 8 different managed servers(with different ports and same IP), and I want to load balance my requests(5 requests per sec). How should I configure it in JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

In HTTP Request, use a Variable for your port :

> ${port}

[image]

Use a [CSV Data Set](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) that will use a CSV file containing 1 row per port:

[image]

To have 5 requests per sec, add a [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) and set its Target Throughput:

[image]

Alternatively you might want to use this 3rd party plugin :

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if it's 1 request you can also split it to 8 requests with different servers and put requests under [Interleave Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Interleave_Controller).

Each request will send to different server.

You can check the `Interleave across threads` checkbox for supporting threads.

> If checked, the interleave controller will alternate among each of its children controllers for each loop iteration but across all threads

For timing use @UBIK LOAD PACK suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In general I don't think that sending requests to different servers is something that real users will do so most probably you will have (or already have) a [load balancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) (or several for failover reasons) in front of your system acting as a single entry and exit point.

So well-behaved JMeter test should target the **load balancer**, not single backend host, this way you will be able to test failover, resilience, load balancing algorithms, etc.

1. Configure your JMeter test to hit the load balancer instead of individual servers
2. Make sure you have [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) added to your Test Plan
3. If needed you can limit JMeter's throughput via [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)

Comment: Hi. You are right. I have added a load balancer now. However earlier I didn't have this, and wanted to make jmeter to send load balanced requests.